# hive first column to consider in partition table

Tags: hadoop, hive

Creating partition table in hive, does it mandatory to choose always the  last column for partition column.
If I choose 1st column as partition, I cant do filter data, is there any way to choose first column for partition?

Answer (score 0):

In hive, if you want to partition a table, you have to define partition column first during table creation time. & while populating the data into table you need to specify as follow:

"INSERT INTO partitioned_table PARTITION(status) SELECT id , name, status from temp_tbl "

in this way using you can partition based on last column only. if you want to partition on the basis of first column. you have to write a Mapreduce job for that . that is the only option available.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem you are facing is that you already have table "source" in your local system or hdfs and you want to upload it to partitioned table. And you want the first column in the source table to be partitioned in hive. As the source table does not have headers i guess we can not do anything here if we try to directly upload the file in the hive destination folder. The only alternate way i know is that create a non partitioned table in hive whose structure is exactly the same as the source file. then upload the source data to non partitioned table first, then copy the data from non partitioned table to partitioned table.
Suppose the source file is like this
`create table source(eid int, ename int, esal int) partitioned by (dept string)`
your non partioned table where you upload the data is like this`create table nopart(dept string, esal int,ename string, eid int)`

then you use the dynamic partition by command `insert overwrite table source partition(dept) select eid,ename,esal,dept from nopart;`
the order of the parameters is the only point here.